# Dialogflow composite entities is changing the order of entities in responses

Tags: dialogflow-es

About composite entities, like CART (@color:color @object:object). Why when I am using the following response: You choosen $cart, sometimes the response is object + color not color + object as choosen in the entitie CART?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is intended as the composite entity is a dictionary of entities and a dictionary is an unordered data structure. The data values are retrieved by keys and not by order. Hence, in composite entities order cannot be preserved. To get the response in order you have to use individual entities to retrieve the values.